# Extracting file extension from filename using Presto

Tags: string, substring, presto

One of the columns in my table has a list of filenames, and I'd like to extract the file extension from this column. Using Presto, how do I extract everything to the right of the last period (`.`)? The file extensions vary in length from 2-4 characters (`.doc, .xls, .xlsx, etc.`)

Answer (score 0):

If a list is a string, then use regexp_extract:

```
select regexp_extract('file1.doc, file3.xls, file2.xlsx','.*\.(.*)$',1) --returns xlsx
```

Regexp `'.*\.(.*)$'` meaning:

`.*` - any character 0+ times

`\.` - dot

`(.*)` - group to extract, any character 0+ times,
you can use `(.{2,4})` - any character 2 to 4 times
or `([^.]*)` - any character except dot 0+ times

`$` - end of the string anchor